# PHPStorm Live templates not expanding

Tags: ide, phpstorm

I've just started to play araound with PHPStorm and I can't get the live templates to work. For example there's one for a public function..'pubf' then tab to expand however when I tab mine out it looks like this...

```
<pubf></pubf>
```

What's going on? Is there a setting I need to enable to get it to work?

Thanks

Comment: Screenshot of a file, please. Whole file in IDE, not just part of it. What you get there is called **Emmet** and such expansion should work in HTML/XML contexts and not in PHP.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It was a question of scope for the template, just needed to select the appropriate file types.

Comment: +1 to your question and answer to increase visibility because others may find this useful

Comment: I use a lot `console.log()` in Javascript. So I finally managed to define abbreviation `csl` with template text `console.log('$s$');`. I wasn't aware of the scope option. Now it's working!

Comment: @AdrianMoisa it is funny, I came to this page looking how to make my `csl` to expand into console.log('$s$') :)

Comment: `...appropriate file types` is the text below the Template text, called `Applicable in`. For my PHP/Blade/HTML I had to choose PHP and HTML.

Answer (score 16):

Just for a little more clarity:

Even though you're under the PHP branch, you still need to apply the abbreviation to an application.  Click the "Define" link and check the PHP box.

[image: Define]

Answer (score 0):

Try:

1. `Settings / Emmet` and changing the default `'Expand abbreviation with'` from `tab` to say `custom`
2. Make sure the context is selected underneath your template text. There is a small `'Change'` link there where you set the context. I had to choose all contexts.